# Translating database tables with gettext

Tags: database, localization, translation, gettext

Is it possible to use gettext to translate content of a database table?

For example, I have some database tables which never change content, e.g. a table which connects country id ("fr", "de",...) with country names ("France", "Germany",...) where country names are written in the English language. I could add additional table columns to provide translation of country names in various languages, but I was wondering, whether it is somehow possible to use gettext for translation of country names.

In case it matters, I use php and mark other fixed strings in the code with `_('text-for-translation')`.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use

```
string gettext ( string $message )
```

where `$message` is your countryname from the db.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So far I am using poedit for translations. Poedit scans all my php files for things like `_('...')` But since the actual country names do not appear in my php code but only in the database, how would poedit know about it?

Comment: I was not sure about your question. No, poedit has no chance to see the items in the database. You would have to export them, translate the words and add them back to the db.

Comment: FWIW, this is the approach I'm planning on using, unless I can find something better.  Of course, like you've observed, you can't rely upon Poedit's "Update" functionality to find the strings to translate.  You'll have to manually modify the `.po`/`.pot` file to include the strings or write a script to automatically do so (I'll likely do the latter).

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but have you tried to add the countries in the Database with the `__();` markup?
So the content of the table look like this:

```
__('Germany');
```

Since gettext translates the same strings anyway you now just open the .po file of the language you like to translate it to in an text editor and add:

```
#: index.php:1
msgid "Germany"
msgstr "Deutschland"
```

You can use any file name or line (that works for me, my Gettext is from [here](https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/+download))

Comment: This would require running PHP's `eval()` on the results from the database, which (beyond being a very atypical solution) introduces a huge security risk.  If an attacker can somehow find a way to modify the value of that field, she can execute whatever code she desires.  In other words, she can change `__('Germany');` to `doSomethingTerrible();`